# How to make the private image accessible with image style?

Tags: files, 9

I have a private image with this URL.

```
http://mystite.com/system/files/images/IMG_0371_24.jpg/IMG_0371_24.jpg
```

An image style is created for the above image on location

```
http://mysite.com/system/files/styles/square/private/images/IMG_0371_24.jpg/IMG_0371_24.jpg
```

The problem is when I display the original image, it works fine. But when I display the image with style, the image is not displaying and in the console, I get 404.

When I try to access the original image through the browser, I can access the image. But when I try to access the image with style in the browser, I get the `The requested page could not be found`.

I can confirm the image is present in the specified location. But don't know what is the issue.

Can anyone tell what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

Actually, the problem is that the image style URLs need an `ITOK` at the end of the URL.

So for that, I used the `buildUrl` function from the image style.

```
$image_style_url = $image_style->buildUrl($original_image_uri);
```

Now this gives a URL like this

```
http://mysite.com/system/files/styles/square/private/images/IMG_0371_24.jpg/IMG_0371_24.jpg?itok=p2-MBbc
```

And now with that URL, I can access the image with an image style.